# Solr query with space, only (#q=%20) stalls

Tags: ajax, solr, solrconfig

I have a web-based frontend (localhost, currently) that uses Ajax to query Solr.

It's working well, but if I submit a single space (nothing else) in the input/search box, the URL in the browser shows

```
...#q=%20
```

and in that circumstance I get a `400 error`, and my web page stalls (doesn't refresh), apparently waiting for a response from Solr.

By comparison, if I submit a semicolon (`;`) rather than a space, then the page immediately refreshes, albeit with no results (`displaying 0 to 0 of 0`; expected).

My question is what is triggering the " " (`%20`) query fault in Solr, and how do I address it in `solrconfig.xml`?

Comment: Don't sent the query to Solr if the request is empty? This is usually an issue with your controller/application and not with Solr. There is also the `q.alt` parameter, which is an alternative query which is used if the `q` parameter is missing or blank (so you can hard code a fallback query): https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Theq.altParameter - but it's usally better to fix this in your controller or applicatio logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update.**  This `solrconfig.xml` entry resolved the `q=%20` issue I described.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
    <str name="hl">off</str>
    <str name="wt">html</str> 
    <str name="df">query</str>
    <!-- *** ADDITION: *** -->
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

---

*Note: development code, dummy data.*

**Before:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhkA4XlqWds&list=PLTtHvbtVBhk6zAqSJ3A1-shsD_h5i3IuP&index=2

**After:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=507DdPOx1xA&list=PLTtHvbtVBhk6zAqSJ3A1-shsD_h5i3IuP&index=1

---

Additional discussion (reddit:Solr): https://old.reddit.com/r/Solr/comments/kt97ql/solr_query_with_space_only_q20_gives_error/